# How to save mlr3 lightgbm model correctly?

Tags: lightgbm, mlr3

I have some following codes. I met error when save trained model.
It's only error when i using `lightgbm`.

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3extralearners)

data = tsk("german_credit")$data()
data = data[, c("credit_risk", "amount", "purpose", "age")]
task = TaskClassif$new("boston", backend = data, target = "credit_risk")

g = po("imputemedian") %>>%
  po("imputeoor") %>>%
  po("fixfactors") %>>%
  po("encodeimpact") %>>% 
  lrn("classif.lightgbm")

gl = GraphLearner$new(g)

gl$train(task)

# predict 
newdata <- data[1,]
gl$predict_newdata(newdata) 
saveRDS(gl, "gl.rds")
```

```r
# read model from disk ----------------
gl <- readRDS("gl.rds")
newdata <- data[1,]

# error when predict ------------------
gl$predict_newdata(newdata)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lightgbm` uses special functions to [save](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R/reference/lgb.save.html) and [read](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R/reference/readRDS.lgb.Booster.html) models. You have to extract the model before saving and add it to the graph learner after loading. However, this might be not practical for benchmarks. We will look into it.

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(lightgbm)

data = tsk("german_credit")$data()
data = data[, c("credit_risk", "amount", "purpose", "age")]
task = TaskClassif$new("boston", backend = data, target = "credit_risk")

g = po("imputemedian") %>>%
  po("imputeoor") %>>%
  po("fixfactors") %>>%
  po("encodeimpact") %>>% 
  lrn("classif.lightgbm")

gl = GraphLearner$new(g)

gl$train(task)

# save model
saveRDS.lgb.Booster(gl$model$classif.lightgbm$model, "model.rda")

# save graph learner
saveRDS(gl, "gl.rda")

# load model
model = readRDS.lgb.Booster("model.rda")

# load graph learner
gl = readRDS("gl.rda")

# add model to graph learner
gl$state$model$classif.lightgbm$model = model

# predict
newdata <- data[1,]
gl$predict_newdata(newdata)
```